# CSS Won't Work Unless More CSS Precedes It

Tags: html, css

I have no idea why this happens but

```
.fade-in
{
    opacity: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-animation: fade-in 2s 2s  ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: fade-in 2s 2s  ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: fade-in 2s 2s  ease-in-out;
    animation: fade-in 2s 2s  ease-in-out;
}
```

will NOT work. However if I do this, it will work and turn white/invisible(though the animation won't run but that is most likely my fault as I am still learning it):

```
.test
{

}
.fade-in
{
    opacity: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-animation: fade-in 2s 2s  ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: fade-in 2s 2s  ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: fade-in 2s 2s  ease-in-out;
    animation: fade-in 2s 2s  ease-in-out;
}
```

Anyone else ever experienced this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This often means that there is garbage appearing right before the non-working CSS rule (and, usually, just after the rule directly above it). This garbage will interfere with the selector, preventing its styles from working. Adding a dummy CSS rule simply serves as a failsafe to prevent the garbage from interfering with your actual CSS rule.

If the garbage is in the form of non-printed characters (which means you can't see them in a normal text editor), you can try to sniff them out by looking at your CSS in a hex editor, or you can just delete everything between the last `}` and the following `{` (including the braces, just in case), retype it, and see if that works:

1. ```
   .example1
   {
       propertyA: value;
       propertyB: value;
   } /* Delete starting from this line */

   .example2
   { /* Delete everything up to this line */
       propertyC: value;
       propertyD: value;
   }
   ```
2. ```
   .example1
   {
       propertyA: value;
       propertyB: value;
       propertyC: value;
       propertyD: value;
   }
   ```
3. ... and retype it.

Be sure to check the encoding of your CSS as well; ideally it should just be encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible for this to happen from copy/pasting? I c/p'd the different browser pre...I have no idea what they are called but I think you know what I mean.

Comment: @user3159486: It *could* - but it's usually difficult to pinpoint the actual cause of these things unless you know what sort of program could have produced these characters depending on what the characters are.